# Variance for the minimum of rolling two six-sided dice.

Tags: probability

What is the variance for the random variable which is the minimum value of rolling two six-sided dice?

I don't know how to approach this problem. To get the variance, I thought I'd calculate the expected value but to do that, I need to use total expectation, and there will be 36 or so different partitions.

Comment: Hint: the minimum (or maximum) of a finite number of identical and independent random variables have a simple form in it CDF. From here you can get easily the PMF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any nonnegative integer valued random variable, $\mathsf E(Y)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathsf P(Y\geq k)$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\min\{X_1,X_2\})~&=~\sum_{k=1}^6 \mathsf P(\min\{X_1,X_2\}\geq k)\\ &= \sum_{k=1}^6 \mathsf P(X_1\geq k, X_2\geq k)\\&=\tfrac 1{36}\sum_{k=1}^6(7-k)^2 \\ &= \tfrac 1{36}\sum_{j=1}^6 j^2
\end{align}$$

Similarly: $\mathsf {E}(Y^2) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty (2k-1)\,\mathsf P(Y\geq k)$ , so:

$$\mathsf E(\min\{X_1,X_2\}^2)=\tfrac {15}{36}\sum_{j=1}^6 j^2-\tfrac 2{36}\sum_{j=1}^6 j^3$$

Comment: Shouldn't that be $(2k-1)$ instead of $k$ for the discrete case of $E[Y^2]$?

Comment: Apparently it should.  I need to revise.

Comment: shouldn't be in the first sum "k=1" instead of "j=1" ?

Comment: typo's doh appen.

Comment: Could you please explain how yout get for "E(Y^2)"  ... 15/36 .... 2/36 ?

Comment: you have another bug. instead of 15 it should be 13, because: P(X_1 = i) * P(X_2 >= i) + P(X_2 = i) * P(X_1 > i) = 1/6 * (7-i)/6 + 1/6 * (6-i)/6 = (13-2i)/36

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are a lot of options; but, we can reduce them through a bit of cleverness.

Instead of coming up with the mass function, let's come up with a CDF; since the outcome is discrete, we can easily compute the mass function from there.

To that end: note that for $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,6\}$, if the first and second rolls are $X_1$ and $X_2$, then
$$
P(\min\{X_1,X_2\}\leq i)=1-P(\min\{X_1,X_2\}>i)=1-P(X_1>i,X_2>i)=1-P(X_1>i)P(X_2>i).
$$
These should, of course, be easily computed. Now, notice that
$$
P(\min\{X_1,X_2\}=i)=P(\min\{X_1,X_2\}\leq i)-P(\min\{X_1,X_2\}\leq i-1),
$$
giving you a PMF.

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this can be easily solved using order statistics. In particular, we are given a parent random variable $X \sim \text{DiscreteUniform}(1,6)$ with pmf say $f(x)$:

[image]

The minimum of two iid samples drawn from the parent corresponds to the $1^\text{st}$ Order Statistic (i.e. sample minimum) in a sample of size 2, which has pmf say $g(x)$:

[image]

for $x \in \{1, 2, \dots, 6\}$, and where I am using the `OrderStat` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to automate the calculation.
 Here is a plot of the pmf of the minimum of two dice $g(x)$:

[image]

We seek $\text{Var}(X)$ when $X$ has pmf $g(x)$:

[image]

which is approximately 1.97145.

**Comparison to other solutions**

The second moment $E_g[X^2]$ is:

[image]

which is different to the solution posted by Graham Kemp of $\mathsf E(\min\{X_1,X_2\}^2)=\tfrac {15}{36}\sum_{j=1}^6 j^2-\tfrac 2{36}\sum_{j=1}^6 j^3$ which evaluates to $\frac{161}{12}$ ( referred to @GrahamKemp )

**Notes**

As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors of the `Var` and `OrderStat` functions used above.